# How to calculate yaw(azimuthal angle) and pitch(polar angle) to direct the camera from one GPS point and altitude to another GPS point and altitude?

Tags: linear-algebra

I can turn my camera with parameters yaw and pitch to direct at some point. Is there a way to get these values (yaw and pitch), if I know the coordinates of the camera (latitude1, longitude1, altitude1) and coordinates of the target (latitude2, longitude2, altitude2)? Camera is also initially directed to somewhere. Its yaw is given in degrees, like azimuth.
The goal is to direct the camera to the target point.

Comment: Convert to Cartesian axis  You should find a reference on the net.

Comment: I found conversions to ECEF coordinates, which I am not sure will help. I saw a solution for cartesian coordinates, but is it also applicable for ECEF x, y, z?

Comment: Try moving from polar to cartesian, move to new observation point and move back to polar

Comment: In my case I also have an initial camera heading, in degrees, like azimuth. Is it possible to take it into consideration while calculating yaw and pitch? I can not imagine those.

Comment: The camera will be the polar system origin and than when you move it, the new one.